# Windows xbuild CS2011 error - Unable to open response file: C:\Program

Tags: windows, mono, xbuild

It's the latest mono release on this date. This appears when running build from TeamCity. Seems like it dosn't work when Mono is installed to directory with spaces in path. The installer does not allow to specify another directory. `mklink` did not help also.

How to fix it?

```
C:\Mono\lib\mono\4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.targets (CoreCompile target) ->
    CSC: error CS2011: Unable to open response file: C:\Program
```

Comment: It would be rather strange to use xbuild on Windows. Can you use MSBuild instead?

Comment: @LexLi The question is not of my current interest now but no, I could not. Because ms build tools 12 can't be installed on that Windows Server version.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760 it does support Windows Server. If you are still using Windows Server 2008, then yes it is time to upgrade, or switch to a Linux machine, instead of resorting to Mono/xbuild on Windows.

Comment: @LexLi yes, we've already upgraded.